# How to create payment page after complete Trial -Developer mode

Tags: web-applications, tableau-api, slack

Currently, am doing for creating a slack application that integrates with tableau, I am going to publish my application into slack."

I need to give 14 days trail use for my customer after that my customer taking to the payment page"

That's my biggest doubt, please solve my issue.

Comment: Hey Vino, your Question is very general, one can give an answer like "Just redirect to the payment page after 14 days after registration" or somtheing like "Just set window.location.href to the URL you want to redirect to", both are way useless to you. Can you be more precise about your question, is it more technically or is it more the workflow you want to get solved ? here is [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general all apps on the Slack app directory a free to download and install. Of course you can offer your app on a trial basis (others do it too), but you will need to implement it yourself.

Here is a rough outline of how to implement a trial period for a Slack app:

- for each Slack workspace record the date & time your app is installed for the first time and set the license mode to trial (e.g. modes are trial, payed)
- for each request from a workspace (e.g. slash command, Interactive action) check if the license is still valid. license is valid if: trial period is not yet expired and license mode for this workspace is payed
- Reply to the request normally if license is valid
- Reply with a "trial period expired" message if license is not valid (and include a link to your "payment page")
- Provide a function for the user to upgrade to payed license on your "payment page"